# Is it possible to do MPC in Drake on a dynamical model, fully or partially described by a neural network?

Tags: drake

I love the MPC module in Drake, providing numerous out-of-the-box cost and constraint functions. The three system building methods I know are importing from a urdf file, LinearSystem, and SymbolicVectorSystem. However, it's hard to include a neural network into the dynamics through them. Is there any suggestion here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use other framework ,like pytorch, to add a neural network to your control system written by drake. They don't conflict.

Comment: To expand on this, you could write your own custom system. Please see the Python tutorial: [drake/tutorials/dynamical_systems.ipynb](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/nightly-release/tutorials/dynamical_systems.ipynb). Note that you can click the Binder button at the top-right. For more info: [user docs](https://drake.mit.edu/#tutorials), [more detailed docs](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/tutorials#running-and-viewing-the-notebooks-online).